# Are these facts about the Poisson process correct?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, poisson-process

Before studying theorems one by one, I want to check whether it is right what I know about Poisson process.

Let $\left\{N(t)\right\}$ be a Poisson process. Then

- the number of the event occur during time $t\sim{}Poisson(\lambda{}t)$
- Each time interval between adjacent events $\sim{}Exponential(\lambda)$
- From any time, time taken until the next event occur $\sim{}Exponential(\lambda)$
- Immediately after an event occur, time until $n$ events occur $\sim{}\Gamma(n, \lambda)$
- From any time, time taken until $n$ events occur  $\sim{}\Gamma(n, \lambda)$

Are there any wrong sentences? If so, let me know what is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: But in general you cannot be sure that the process $N(t)$ is a homogeneous Poisson process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, those are correct. Here is more useful information:

- The interarrival times are iid's.
- The conditional distribution of arrival time $T_1$, $\:P[T_1 \leq \tau \mid N(t)=1]$
  with $\tau \leq t$ is uniformly distributed over $(0,t)$, $\:P[T_1 \leq \tau \mid N(t)=1] = \frac{\tau}{t}$. And this generalizes to later times.
- A PP has independent increments.
- A PP has stationary increments.
- A PP is nonstationary, like any process with stationary independent increments.
- A PP is a renewal process with exponentially distributed intervals.

Comment: I'm impressed with your nice answer. Thank you.